# Comparison of incoming error strings to known set and transformation into 3rd string

Tags: python, strings

I have a function where I am comparing an error string returned from a web service to several lists of known strings, and then based on which list the error is a member of, returning from the function a more 'user-friendly' error to display.

I am hoping someone could offer some tips on making it shorter and more efficient.  I think I'm missing some obvious shortcuts, but I am not sure what.

```
def interpret_error(error):
    display_error_1 = 'User error 1'

    display_error_2 = 'User error 2'

    display_error_3 = 'User error 3'


    error_list_1= ["Failure: 'mean_va' is not in list",
                   "Failure: No JSON object could be decoded",
                   "Failure: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 14410098 (char 14410097)",
                   "Failure: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ContentDecodingError' objects",
                   "Failure: Unknown error",
                   "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: No Results Returned"]

    error_list_2 = ["Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: Flowline comid 4505568 at measure 79.99388 not found in NHDPlus stream network",
                    "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: No Catchments match navigation results"]

    error_list_3 = ["Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: Start permid must have a hydroseq greater than the hydroseq for stop permid",
                    "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: Start measure must be greater than stop measure when navigating a single reach"]

    match1 = 0.0
    match2 = 0.0
    match3 = 0.0
    temp_match = 0.0

    for internal_error in error_list_1:
        temp_match = fuzz.token_set_ratio(error,internal_error)
        match1 = max(temp_match, match1)

    temp_match = 0.0

    for internal_error in error_list_2:
        temp_match = fuzz.token_set_ratio(error,internal_error)
        match2 = max(temp_match, match2)

    temp_match = 0.0

    for internal_error in error_list_3:
        temp_match = fuzz.token_set_ratio(error,internal_error)
        match3 = max(temp_match, match3)

    if match1 > match2 and match1 > match3:
        return display_error_1
    elif match2 > match1 and match2 > match3:
        return display_error_2
    elif match3 > match1 and match3 > match2:
        return display_error_3
    else:
        return "Error of unknown cause"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner for loops can be made easier:

```
match1 = max(fuzz.token_set_ratio(error, internal_error) for internal_error in error_list1)
```

And similar for match2 and match3.

However, the real complixity in your implementation lies in the determining of the error message to show.

I would suggest building a dictionary mapping the display error to internal errors:

```
def interpret_error(error):
    error_mapping = {
        "User error 1": [
            "Failure: 'mean_va' is not in list",
            "Failure: No JSON object could be decoded",
            "Failure: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 14410098 (char 14410097)",
            "Failure: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ContentDecodingError' objects",
            "Failure: Unknown error",
            "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: No Results Returned",
        ],
        "User error 2": [
            "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: Flowline comid 4505568 at measure 79.99388 not found in NHDPlus stream network",
            "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: No Catchments match navigation results",
        ],
        "User error 3": [
            "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: Start permid must have a hydroseq greater than the hydroseq for stop permid",
            "Failure: Error returned by EPA WATERS web service: Start measure must be greater than stop measure when navigating a single reach",
        ],
    }

    display_error = None
    score = 0.0
    for message, internal_errors in error_mapping.items():
        tmp = max(fuzz.token_set_ratio(error, internal_error) for internal_error in internal_errors)

        # This matches better than any earlier internal_error.
        if tmp >= score:
            score = tmp
            display_error = message

    return display_error
```

Ideally: move the mapping to a separate `.py` file, or some form of config file (`.json`, `.yaml` or even `.xml`), or the database.

Comment: very insightful implementation - I'm not sure if I'm willing to implement the second part of it though  - it's a trade off there of fewer lines, but much harder to understand code.  If I were a better programmer, I would probably take both your suggestions - but my own limitations and those for whom I'm building this script, might relegate me to leaving out that part of your suggestion for now.